# Get Push Notifications on App's Foreground mode in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, push-notification, foreground

I am getting **Push Notifications**, when my app is in **background mode** but the notification is **not showing** when the app is in **foreground mode**.

I searched a lot about this issue and they say, you have to implement

> willPresent notification: UNNotification

function but I already have this function. Below is my **App Delegate's** code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
      /// code for push notifications
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
      
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
          
          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }
      
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      
      
      return true
  }
    /// code for notifications
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

         if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
             Helper.shared.printDebug("Message ID: \(messageID)")
         }

        Helper.shared.printDebug(userInfo)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            
            if userInfo["other_data"] as? String == "Request Notification" {
                
                
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("request_notification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            } else {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("message_notification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            }
        }
        
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
       }
}
/// code for push notifications
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

      let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        Helper.shared.printDebug("Device token: \(deviceToken)") // This token can be used for testing notifications on 
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: UserDefaultEnum.deviceId.rawValue)
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        Helper.shared.printDebug("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

      Helper.shared.printDebug(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
  }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Helper.shared.printDebug(deviceToken)
        
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        Helper.shared.printDebug(error.localizedDescription)
    }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          Helper.shared.printDebug("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
      }
      Helper.shared.printDebug(userInfo)
      
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
          
          if userInfo["other_data"] as? String == "Request Notification" {
              
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("request_notification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
          } else {
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("message_notification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
          }
      }
      
      completionHandler()
  }
}
```

App's notification's settings are:

[image: settings image]

Can someone help me out with this issue?

I am using xCode 14.3 and iOS 16.5